# Check if Class is Nothing, or Structure is default value, using a single condition

Tags: .net, vb.net, reference, null, default-value

I've written my own method for programmatically selecting an item in a ComboBox:

```
Function SelectItem(ByVal item As Object, ByVal comboBox As ComboBox) As Boolean
  If Not comboBox.Items.Contains(item) Then
    comboBox.Items.Add(item)
  End If

  comboBox.SelectedItem = item

  Return True
End Function
```

The "item" parameter can be any `Class`, like a String, but it can also be a (custom) `Structure`.

When the parameter is `Nothing` (or the default structure value), this method should return `False`. How do I achieve this condition?

```
' This will not work, because "=" can't be used with classes
If item = Nothing Then Return False

' Won't work either, because "Is" is always False with structures
If item Is Nothing Then Return False

' Obviously this would never work
If item.Equals(Nothing) Then Return False

' Tried this too, but no luck :(
If Nothing.Equals(item) Then Return False
```

How should I handle this condition? I could use `Try ... Catch`, but I know there must be a better way.

Comment: `item` is `object` - you should be able to test an `object` for `null` without any problem!? however, there is no easy way to detect a "default value" of a struct - after all, all-zeros is usually a valid value

Comment: for value type you can use If obj.GetType.IsValueType Then ....

Comment: @MarcGravell - you are right about `Is`. I've edited my post. But using `Is` will not achieve my goal, which is detecting the default value in case of a structure.

Comment: @MarcGravell - by the way, there **is** an easy way to detect the default value of a structure, by using `= Nothing`. For example, the comparison `0 = Nothing` will return `True` in VB.NET.

Comment: @Ric - but if `obj` is `Nothing`, `obj.GetType()` will throw a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function does the trick:

```
Public Function IsNullOrDefaultValue(item As Object) As Boolean
    Return item Is Nothing OrElse (item.GetType.IsValueType Andalso item = Nothing)
End Function
```

Test results by passing variable:

```
Dim emptyValue As Integer = 0          ==> True
Dim emptyDate As DateTime = Nothing    ==> True
Dim emptyClass As String = Nothing     ==> True
Dim emptyStringValue As String = ""    ==> False
Dim stringValue As String = "aa"       ==> False
Dim intValue As Integer = 1            ==> False
```

Comment: No, it does not. Take a look at the first condition after the `Return` statement. `item Is Nothing` always returns `True` with structures, as stated in my question.

Comment: No, did you test it? I will edit with the results or my test.

Comment: Then reversing the conditions should take care of it: `If (item.GetType.IsValueType AndAlso item = Nothing) OrElse Item Is Nothing`. The `item = Nothing` won't be attempted if the object is a reference type.

Comment: Actually, Is Nothing always returns `False` for a value type wrapped in an object, not `True`.

Comment: @Meta-Knight - oops, you're right. I must have had a `Not` somewhere when I tested it.

Comment: After your edit it does not work anymore. Since you removed the value type check, an exception will be thrown when the parameter is a not-null reference type. Using `New Object()` breaks it. However, the old version works fine.

Comment: @RuudLenders: You're right, it only worked when the type implements `=`, which is the case for basic types but not necessarily for custom classes. I removed that part.

Comment: @Meta-Knight - It does not work when a custom structure is used that has not overloaded the `=` operator. Do you know how I can solve that *without overloading the operator in every structure*? I hoped to solve it by replacing the `=` operator with `Equals` method, but no luck...

Comment: @RuudLenders: I think that the only way to check for the default value is to compare it to `Nothing` with the `=` operator. So if you have a custom structure, you need to override `=`. Otherwise, how would you tell what is the default value for your custom structure?

Comment: @Meta-Knight - Even if a structure has not overloaded `=`, you can still compare it using `Equals`. But in some cases `Equals` returns `False`, while `=` returns `True`, so I can't trust it. You are right, the `=` operator must be overloaded.

Comment: @RuudLenders: Yes, that's what I found out. It's strange but Equals does not work for comparing with the default value, only `=`. Handling of default values is one of the worst parts of VB.NET :S  I especially dislike the use of the same keyword (Nothing) to stand for null values AND default values.

Comment: @Meta-Knight - I couldn't agree more with you. If I was coding my current project in C# I would probably never had to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't quite sure in which conditions you wanted to return True/False, but this code shows how you can check the type and compare it to a specific value. This way you're not trying to compare it to a value if it's the wrong type.

```
If (TypeOf myVar is MyClass andalso myVar isnot nothing) _
    OrElse TypeOf myVar is MyStructure AndAlso myVar = MyStructure.DefaultValue) Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: My method is supposed to work with **any** `Class` or `Structure`, so I can't use `TypeOf`.